# CSS Selector: use attr() as value

Tags: css

i'm trying to select a item dynamically with the help of css attr(). In this case I want to show only elements which contains the attribute "data-color" in the attribute "data-media".

I'm planning to do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="item" data-media="item_GG_Front.jpg" data-color="_CDMR_">don't show item</div>
<div class="item" data-media="item_CDMR_Front.jpg" data-color="_CDMR_">show item</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
   display: none;
}
.item[data-media*="attr('data-color')"] {
   display: block;
}
```

Is this possible with CSS? Because I don't want to declare all color options. I must declare this very flexible, because the attribute "data-color" changes dynamically with Javascript.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you cannot do this with CSS

Comment: If "data-color changes dynamically with Javascript", why not do the comparison at that point and add a selector you can use in your CSS e.g. `data-matches="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution in javascript at the bottom of your html :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item[data-media][data-color]').forEach(e => {
    if(e.getAttribute('data-media').includes(e.getAttribute('data-color'))) {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

You just have to let the css :

```
.item {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question, I believe they are asking for a way to check if the `data-media` contains `data-color` as a substring, rather than simply having both attributes.

Comment: I misunterstood the question. So It is not possible to do that in CSS, CSS is static. It is possible to find a solution in javascript

Comment: Okay thank you. This is also my fallback idea, if it is not possible with css.